# Using WURFL library to detect device width and height

Tags: wurfl

I am using the WURFL library to return device width and height.

I used Safari with iPhone agent but the result is null.

My code is:

```
$width = $wurfl->getDeviceCapability("resolution_width");
$height = $wurfl->getDeviceCapability("resolution_height");
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you first query the device capabilities using the user agent string `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`?

```
$wurfl = new TeraWurfl();
$wurfl->getDeviceCapabilitiesFromAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

$width  = (int) $wurfl->getDeviceCapability('resolution_width');
$height = (int) $wurfl->getDeviceCapability('resolution_height');
```

Using `Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU iPhone OS 4_3 like Mac OS X; de-de) AppleWebKit/533.17.9 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/8F190` the result of $width is 320 and of $height 480.